# nolink class added with <a> for every ul and li

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

In Joomla 3.0, an empty `<a>` tag with `class="nolink"`(ie,) is inserted for every `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Advice me how to remove this.

We are creating the component and we are creating the tabs as of default component (for ex Newsfeed component edit page).On the first tab position the `<a>` tag is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following code in the `function addtoolbar` in the `view.html.php` file.

Change the mainmenu params as false in the edit page view.

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('hidemainmenu', false);
```

If we need to display the mainmenu using the above code, then the following code `<a class="nolink"></a>` doesn't generate in the edit page.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found the problem.
This is due to a tag which is unclosed in the `/administrator/modules/mod_submenu/tmpl/default.php` file in line 26.

A ticket has already been created on JoomlaCode: [[#29623] Missing closing link tag in submenu layout](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=29623)

We just have to wait the next Joomla version.

You can also add the `'</a>'` tag at the end of the line 26 like this:

```
?><a class="nolink"><?php echo $item[0]; ?></a><?php
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the default editors that came with Joomla 3.0: 
(In Users -> User Manager -> Super User -> Basic Settings -> Editor:)

Editor - CodeMirror

Editor - None

Editor - TinyMCE

That problem didn't occur here. I also tried using the button on TinyMCE editor to add the ul and li tags.

Can you give more details on how did you add those ul and li tags?
What editor are you using?